# Custom ListboxItem with Template Command Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, controltemplate

I try to build a custom ListboxItem, but I struggle with binding a Command to my TemplateControl.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type controls:NavigationRailItem}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:NavigationRailItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:NavigationRailItem}" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <StackPanel.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"/>
                    </StackPanel.InputBindings>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{TemplateBinding IconKind}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
public class NavigationRailItem : ListBoxItem
{
    static NavigationRailItem()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NavigationRailItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NavigationRailItem)));
    }

    public PackIconKind IconKind
    {
        get { return (PackIconKind)GetValue(IconKindProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconKindProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconKindProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IconKind), typeof(PackIconKind), typeof(NavigationRailItem), new PropertyMetadata(default(PackIconKind)));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(NavigationRailItem), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Command.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(NavigationRailItem), 
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));
}
```

In my MainWindow I try to bind the Command to my ViewModel. If I try to bind my DependencyProperty directly I don't get the Click event.
If I bind it in the MainWindow again with InputBinding I get it. The last test is the native implementation using the ListboxItem directly.

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Controls1:NavigationRailItem IconKind="Car" Text="Test1" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
    <Separator Height="10"/>
    <Controls1:NavigationRailItem IconKind="XboxLive" Text="Test2" >
        <Controls1:NavigationRailItem.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
        </Controls1:NavigationRailItem.InputBindings>
    </Controls1:NavigationRailItem>
    <ListBoxItem >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
            <StackPanel.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel.InputBindings>
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Apple"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Test3" FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Can anybody tell me what I do wrong? I want to understand how to build own controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TemplateBinding` Can only be used within a `ControlTemplate`. So to fixing the problem, In your control template change this line:

```xml
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"/>
```

to this:

```xml
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Command}"/>
```